How to mask a tensor without losing the gradient?
I have a tensor
import torch
a = torch.randn(1, 3, requires_grad=True)
print('a: ', a)
>>> a:  tensor([[0.0200, 1.00200, -4.2000]], requires_grad=True)

And a mask
mask = torch.zeros_like(a)
mask[0][0] = 1

I want to mask my tensor a without propagating the gradients to my mask tensor (in my real case it has a gradient). I tried to the following
with torch.no_grad():
    b = a * mask
    print('b: ', b)
    >>> b:  tensor([[0.0200, 0.0000, -0.0000]])

But it removes the gradient entirely from my tensor. What is the correct way to do it?

You can call detach on the mask tensor to remove it from the gradient chain.
a = torch.randn(1, 3, requires_grad=True)

mask = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 0.]], requires_grad=True)

mask_no_grad = mask.detach()

b = a * mask_no_grad
print(b)
> tensor([[0.3871, 0.0000, -0.0000]], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)


But then it propagates to my masking tensor, which I don't want

What do you mean "propagates to the masking tensor"? The mask tensor itself has no gradient.

I wrote above "in my real case it has a gradient"

Well you made that very confusing by explicitly creating a with a gradient and mask without in your example. I've updated the answer to show using detach to take the mask out of the gradient chain
